# Basic iOS Line of Code Explanation

Tags: ios

The [tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/DesigningDataModel/DesigningDataModel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011318-CH3-SW2) I am working on has the following method defined.

```
- (void)addBirdSightingWithSighting:(BirdSighting *)sighting {
    [self.masterBirdSightingList addObject:sighting];
}
```

The tutorial describes this as follows:

> This method creates and initializes a new `BirdSighting` object by sending to the `initWithName:location:date:` method the name and location the user entered, along with today’s date. Then, the method adds the new `BirdSighting` object to the array.

There is a `initWithName:location:date:` method that is on the `BirdSighting` class which is my data model. The above method is added to the data controller which simply is adding a `BirdSighting` object to the `masterBirdSightingList` mutable array.

What I do not understand is that the tutorial says that `BirdSighting` object is sent to the `initWithName:location:date:` method when I do not see this?

- Is this because the `*` in the `(BirdSighting *)` method parameter? I understand that the `*` is a pointer to a object, but does it create a new object and call its default init method? And just because I added the `initWithName:location:date` to the `BirdSighting` class, does it automatically become my default `init` method?

Comment: Can you link to the tutorial?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/DesigningDataModel/DesigningDataModel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011318-CH3-SW2     Scroll down to the bottom and click 'To Implement the Data Controllers Data Access Methods'

Comment: Clearly just a mistake in the text. This is just adding a `BirdSighting` object (created elsewhere) to the `masterBirdSightingList`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No magic there. You're right. That line of code does not create or initialize a BirdSighting object.

**Added:**

You've discovered, perhaps sooner than many, that neither the Apple code nor docs are perfect. Sometimes they even have serious issues. When you encounter a dissonance, it's best to trust your intuition and do some of your own testing.

Comment: Checked out the link; definitely looks like a mistake in the tutorial. There's a link at the bottom of the Apple docs where you can report problems like that.

Comment: thanks noa for the help, I was stuck on that sentence for for a minute. I have reported the issue to Apple.